# Receive data from weighing scale continuously

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, serial-port

I am working on Windows 6 application in Visual Studio 2008 (C#). I am trying to receive weight from weighing scale. I am able to receive weight, but whenever weight gets changed on weighing scale it is not getting the changed weight. It is continuously showing the same weight in code.

For example: on starting the app it is showing correct weight (00000) continuously, then I changed the object on the weighing scale (new weight 00020) but still it is showing the previous weight (00000) in app.

My code is as follows:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string hex;
    public bool isSet = false;
    private SerialPort _serialPort;         //<-- declares a SerialPort Variable to be used throughout the form
    private const int BaudRate = 2400;      //<-- BaudRate Constant. 9600 seems to be the scale-units default value

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM5", BaudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);       //<-- Creates new SerialPort using the name selected in the combobox
    }

    private delegate void Closure();
    private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    {           
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {   //<-- Makes sure the function is invoked to work properly in the UI-Thread

                BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { SerialPortOnDataReceived(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));     //<-- Function invokes itself

        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";

            while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0) //<-- repeats until the In-Buffer is empty
            {                   
                    //MessageBox.Show("byte");
                hex += string.Format("{0:X2} ", _serialPort.ReadByte());                   

            }
            if (hex != "")
            {
                byte[] data = FromHex(hex.Trim());
                textBox1.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length).Trim();
                isSet = true;                    
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = "no";
            }
        }
    }

    public byte[] FromHex(string aHex)
    {
        aHex = aHex.Replace(" ", "");
        byte[] raw = new byte[aHex.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
        {
            raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(aHex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }
        return raw;
    } 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isSet = false;
        textBox1.Text = "";


        _serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPortOnDataReceived;       //<-- this event happens everytime when new data is received by the ComPort
        try
        {
            _serialPort.Open();     //<-- make the comport listen
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex2.Message);
        }
        textBox1.Text = "Listening on " + _serialPort.PortName + "...\r\n";
    }
}
```

**Please let me know if my question is not clear.**

Comment: Your code appears to only start receiving if the user clicks a button. Did you click the button? Assuming you've clicked the button, have you checked to see whether your event handler is called or not? Also, your code to receive the data is pretty odd, though it probably would work. Instead of converting bytes to hexadecimal text then back to bytes then to ASCII, you should just call the `ReadExisting()` method, which will automatically convert _all_ of the available bytes to ASCII and return that as a string.

Comment: You are quietly ignoring that catch all exception when you open the port. Remove that try catch for debugging or at least uncomment the output. Also, try setting a break point in the data Rx handler just to make sure data is flowing.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Have used ReadExisting() and my problem got resolved. Now I am able to receive weight continuously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `ReadExisting()` in place of `ReadByte()` resolved my problem.